# streaming - how to stream a video without saving it to server

Tags: html, video, stream, embed

I need to do stream a a live video. So far I used vlc to create a stream to a ffserver, convert it, save it then embed the created file into the html.

The only problem is that I need to do this without saving to a file (because it gets a little... 2 big).

Answer (score 2):

If you feel like trying out a "newborn" program for the job, I would recommed giving my very new [WebM-based streaming server](http://code.google.com/p/stream-m/) a test drive. - Feel free to use the issue tracker if you encounter any quirks.

The only downside is that it is strictly WebM-centric, so IE and Safary will not play it natively.